# training multiple sequence alignment in autoencoder

Tags: python, autoencoder

I have some code that I am trying to run. But I have a problem with the code. The code is from the internet page. My data is multiple sequence alignment of a specific protein. Firstly I applied one-hot encoding and then tried to put it into a variational autoencoder for training. But I failed. when I ran this code, I got the error message about ''' Input 0 of layer "encoder" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), found shape=(None, 13, 1)''''
As I am a beginner in this field, I don't know where I made a mistake. would you please help with this issue? Or how to train it with multiple sequence alignment data?

###################################

datax = pd.DataFrame({'sequence':['ACKIENIKYKGKEVESKLGSQLIDIFNDLDRAKEEYDKLSSPEFIAKFGDWINDEVERNVNEDGEPLLIQDVRQDSSKHYFFILKNGERFDLLTR','---------TGKEVQSSLFDQILELVKDPQLAQDAYAQIRTPEFIEKFGDWINDPYESKLDDNGEPILIE-------------------------','-------PNTGKEVQSSLFDQIIELIKDPKLAQDAYEQVRTPEFIEKFGDWINDPYAAKLDDNGEPILVERD-----------------------','-------PNQGKEVESKLYNDLVNLTGSEKAADEAYEQVHHPNFLRWFGDWINNKVSNVVDENGEPLIV--------------------------','ACRIIISLNKGKEVKSKLFDSLLDLTQSEAKAEEAYKKVFSEEFINWFGDWINTPASKVVDENGEPLMVYRFTQEE-------------------','-------PNKGKEVRSKLYDDLLELTGDDNAALEAYKKVHHPNFLRWFGDWINNKVSKVVDENGEPLIVY-------------------------','-------PNKGKEVESKLYNDLVNLTGSEKAADEAYTKVHHPNFLRWFGDWMTNPSSKVVDENGEPKIV--------------------------','-------PNKGQRVDSILYNDLLSLTGNEKSADKAYTKAHTSSFLNWFGDWINTNIQDNVDQNGEPKV---------------------------','-----------------------------NLTSEQYKLVRTPEFIAWFGNWMDDPNASVIDENGEPLVCFH-GTDNSFHIF--------------','---------------------------------KQWVQVRTPAFIEWFGDWMNDPASKGVDENGEPLVVYHGTENKFTQYDFD------------','-------------------------------TPKQYKLVRTLEFKAWFGDWENDPASKVVDENGEPLVVYH--GTDSKHNVFSYEQ---------','--------------GSSLYEQYVVIIDSSNLTTEQYKLVRTPEFKKWFGDWENNPSEAVVDENGEPLVVYH------------------------','------------------------------LTPEQYKLVRTPEFKAWFGDWENNPSSKVVDDNGEPMVVY---HGSRKKAFTEFK----------']})

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import pandas as pd


encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

onehot = encoder.fit_transform(datax)
print(onehot)


class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


latent_dim = 10

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()


class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(datax, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

data_digits = np.concatenate([train, test], axis=0)
data_digits = np.expand_dims(data_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(mnist_digits, epochs=1, batch_size=128)
```

##########################################

Comment: Check the input shape of your model, it is set to take images, did you try to debug this problem by yourself?

Comment: thank you for your reply. yes, I tried but I failed. I have only sequences. I do one-hot coding after typing the sequences in the data frame.